# Ubuntu 18.04 start mysql without root privilege

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, workbench, ubuntu-18.04

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 and installed LAMP on it, however I had trouble using mysql without the root privilege. when I write:

> mysql -u root -p

and enter the password I configured it throws access denied. unless if I write

> sudo mysql -u root -p

and enter the password that I'm able to connect. But I don't want the sudo cause it prevents having workbench to connect to mysql, same applies to phpmyadmin too. Any hints on how to fix that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I appreciate your concern and advice, however checking the link you shared on what to ask about the question would fall into this category "software tools commonly used by programmers;"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should only be the "-u root" user that requires sudo. It's good practice to not use root for most access anyways, so just login as root using sudo and create a newuser:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

Then you should be able to access "mysql -u newuser" without sudo.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced this problem yesterday. To solve this problem follow these steps:

1. Connect to MySQL: `sudo mysql -u root`
2. Check for mysql users in db: `SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;`
3. Drop root user account: `DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';`
4. Recreate root user: `CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ''`
5. Grant all privileges to root user: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
6. Set password for root user: `ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';`

That's it! Now you should be able to connect the MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the help although it did not work on the third step, however the first answer worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with mysql version 5.7 in workbench but solved this by following these 10 steps

1. Connect to MySQL: `sudo mysql -u root`
2. Check for mysql users in db: `SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;`
3. Drop root user account: `DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';`
4. `SET GLOBAL validate_password_length = 5;`
5. `SET GLOBAL validate_password_number_count = 0;`
6. `SET GLOBAL validate_password_mixed_case_count = 0;`
7. `SET GLOBAL validate_password_special_char_count = 0;`
8. `SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy = LOW;`
9. Recreate root user: `CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin'`
10. Grant all privileges to root user: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0UnL.png) 1. UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'root' AND plugin = 'unix_socket';

2.FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't connect to mysql with any mysql user without sudo, try:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

or

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/run/mysql/
```

then restart the service

```
sudo services mysql start
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```